# To download only android sdk while installing xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I had started to download `xamarin` to code in `c#` for `android` app development. I *don't* want to download `ios` related or other thing while downloading xamarin since the **size is too big** nearly 1.5 gb.

So, I am looking for any way to download only `android` related while installing `xamarin`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [Xamarin Manual Installation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/) documentation found here